# Tomcat 7 and Java 8 compatibility issue

Tags: java-8, tomcat7

Installing Oracle Java 8 and pointing tomcat7 to java8 produced the following error as per catalina.out:

```
            INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
            Sep 22, 2015 9:14:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
            SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
            org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1095)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1617)
                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
            Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:131)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2032)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1923)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1891)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1877)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:855)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                    ... 10 more

            Sep 22, 2015 9:14:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
            SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1095)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1617)
                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

            Sep 22, 2015 9:14:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
            INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
            Sep 22, 2015 9:14:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
            INFO: Server startup in 1308 ms
```

I'm using:--
Tomcat version: 7.0.26 & 
Oracle Java: 8

I've seen lot of posts suggesting to upgrade Tomcat to 7.0.53 or higher. But is there any workaround to resolve the issue without upgrading Tomcat?

Comment: Literally reading suggest something with class files is wrong. ... strange ... I had many upgrades Java7 -> 8 + Tomcat7 without problems (7.0.2x, now 7.0.54)

Comment: Probably a Tomcat version >= 7.30 will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your Tomcat to at least 7.0.30.
It should work because this [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53735) was fixed.