# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.time4j.tz.TZID

Tags: java, servlets, classnotfoundexception

I want to use time4j (http://www.time4j.net/) in servlet, but when I use this code:

```
    PlainDate date = PlainDate.of(2014, 3, 21);
    int dayOfMonth = date.get(PlainDate.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    PlainTimestamp tsp = date.atStartOfDay();
```

in doGet method or outside it I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.time4j.tz.TZID
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1297)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1131)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: There aren't any errors in your posted output. They're all INFO logs.

Comment: Sorry! I have already added errors!

Comment: At least from that error, I don't see that it necessarily has anything to do with the posted code.

Comment: Maybe this is similar to a problem posted in another [SO-question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864778/tomcat-7-and-java-8-compatibility-issue). I don't see how the Time4J-code shown above can produce an exception (well tested - even as integration simple servlet test on Tomcat). It can only be located around some weird classloading features of Tomcat. Maybe an update of Tomcat version helps.

Comment: Thanks, Meno Hochschild for your answer but I have tried with the ninth version of Tomcat as well.

Comment: Next time you get an exception, focus on the bottommost "Caused by" part. That's the Mother Of All Causes. All causes there above are just consequences which should disappear (or change) when the Mother Of All Causes is solved.

Comment: In your pom which is the scope of the net.time4j dependency?

Comment: Baldurian, finally I have added all in pom:  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>time4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>time4j-calendar</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>time4j-i18n</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version> ETC.....

Comment: BalusC, thanks! I am new programmer :)

Comment: Now I've tried with Joda time, the same problem:
root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:

Comment: Solved! I use Java 1.8, I copied 3 jars (time4j-core-4.11.jar, time4j-core-4.11-javadoc.jar, time4j-core-4.11-sources.jar) to WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib. Also here is my pom:
            <groupId>net.time4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>time4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>

Comment: Congratulations for having found a solution. However, I assume you had a typo in your last comment and wanted to say: "time4j-core-4.11.jar, time4j-i18n-4.11.jar, time4j-calendar-4.11.jar)". It does not make sense to include sources or javadoc in WEB-INF/lib-directory, because only the binary distribution is useful in that directory. And I recommend to use newest version v4.15 because it has two additional calendars (ThaiSolar+Julian), enhancements of historic calendars and several improvements of the parse engine.